# Xcrun is not embedding passed provisioning profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, xcrun

I have "myApp.app" package that was build using command line. This app package contains distribution profile inside. Now, I need to make separate ipa package for testing (sign with development profile) so I'm executing xcrun command:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "./MyApp.app" -o "./MyApp.ipa" --sign "iPhone Developer: My Name (XXX)” -- embed "XXX.mobileprovision"
```

The problem is the ipa is created but with the same distribution app store provisioning profile. In console everything looks fine:

```
Codesigning ...
app: replacing existing signature
```

It looks like xcrun is ignoring --embed and --sign values. I triple checked mobile provisioning profile - its number is correct and it existing inside ProvisioningProfiles directory. The same is OK with --sign value. Any ideas?

The interesting part is if I archive the app through Xcode and then create ipa file through Organizer then Organizer asks we to select profile and it creates correct ipa file after I select iOS team provisioning profile. But Xcode debug console is showing the log only for archive process, so I see only the packaging part with distribution profile. It does not show organizer->distribute->AddHoc step in console when I select iOS Team provisioning profile, so values for --sign and --embed and I wrote manually by checking profile with TextEdit and looking inside Name (iOS Team provisioning).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command looks okay, except that there is a space between "--" and "embed", could it be the problem?